# Согласимся ли с новомодным "отзвониться"?

Tags: словообразование

В последние годы часто можно услышать фразы типа "Я тебе отзвонюсь на следующей неделе"  вместо "Я тебе позвоню..." Мне кажется, что это сленговое словечко, так как приставка "от" обычно  употребляется в значениях "отделить (отрезать), завершить (отыграть(ся), отвезти, отругать) и т.д." Никакой, даже отдаленной причины для употребления слова "отзвониться" я не вижу. Каково мнение коллег по этому вопросу? Войдет ли это слово в нормативный словарь?

Comment: А я вместо "Я вам позвоню" часто слышу "Я вас наберу". Вот это точно сленг.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разным оттенкам речи - своё место. Это подходит для ситуаций, когда кто-то обещал или обязан был по долгу службы отчитаться по телефону перед кем-то - на основании запланированного получения новой информации. Трудно представить себе в новостях фразу: "Путин отзвонился Меркель по поводу её предложения недельной давности". Чисто языковые претензии к слову тоже можно предъявить (напоминает слово "отделаться" - позвонив и этим покончив с выполнением обещания). Поэтому возникает желание ограничить употребление слова неформальными или профессиональными случаями (в проф. речи часто допускаются отклонения от общих норм).

Answer (score 6):

> можно услышать фразы типа "Я тебе отзвонюсь на следующей неделе"

Мне кажется, это что-то вроде слова **"отчитаться"**. Что-то близкое по смыслу.

Например. *"Я как следует разберусь с этим делом, а потом отчитаюсь/отзвонюсь тебе"*.

В том случае, когда слово *"отзвонюсь"* употребляется на разговорном, неформальном, уровне, то лично у меня отрицательных эмоций оно не вызывает (если вы об *этом* спрашивали).

Answer (score 0):

По-польски oddzwonić = "перезвонить". Может быть, дело в заимствовании? :)